# Can I start building my drupal 8 theme?

Tags: drupal-8

Is the Drupal 8 template engine ready for a new development?

I plan to use Drupal 8, and since I will start first with the design, I want to know if the template engine (I understand it uses Twig) will suffer significative changes that doesn't make it a good choice to start now.

Comment: The second release candidate for Drupal 8 has arrived a couple of days ago: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598668

The release of Drupal 8 is scheduled to be released November 19th, so there shouldn't be any big changes to the template engine anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 is currently in Beta 1, and according to the Beta 1 release notes:

> **Drupal 8 beta 1 for designers, translators, and documentation writers**
>
> Drupal 8's user interface, interface text, and markup are not
>   finalized until the first release candidate, so it's too early to
>   focus on user-facing documentation, translations, or themes (though by
>   all means, adventurous contributors should start now to provide
>   feedback while we can still fix things). Note that localize.drupal.org
>   does not yet support the full Drupal 8 API and does not have all
>   translatable strings.

https://www.drupal.org/drupal-8.0.0-beta1

Comment: Yes, maybe lacking docs on updated beta (11): https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 is now released. If you're looking for a couple of theming how-to overviews we've written a couple:
[Custom Drupal 8 Theme + Sass, Singularity, Breakpoint, LiveReload and Gulp](http://www.reallifedigital.com/blog/how-we-got-custom-drupal-8-theme-and-running-sass-singularity-breakpoint-livereload-and-gulp) and [Kickstarting with Drupal 8 themes](http://www.reallifedigital.com/blog/kickstarting-drupal-8-themes).

Hope you find them helpful!